# Global initialization of instance

Tags: c++

I need to create **global** initialization of instance.

*untitled.ino*

```
#include "own_library.h"
own_library test(1, 2, 3);

void setup() {
} 

void loop() {
}
```

*own_library.h*

```
#ifndef own_library_h
#define own_library_h

class own_library {
   public:
       own_library(byte one, byte two, byte three);
   private:
};

#endif
```

*own_library.cpp*

```
#include <foreign_library.h>

#include "own_library.h"

own_library::own_library(byte one, byte two, byte three) {
    foreign_library test = foreign_library(one, two, three);
}

// i need to work with foreign library under this comment //
```

The main problem is, the instance is created just in constructor, so as local instance.

Comment: Make `foreign_library test` a (`private`) class member variable and initialize it in the constructors member initializer list.

Comment: "I need to create global initialization of instance." This is almost certainly not true. Rather there's some problem you have that you think this is the correct method to solve. But you don't tell us what that problem is, so we can't really understand what it is that you're trying to do, and that makes it hard for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You do not most likely want a *global instance*, rather you want your foreign library object to be accessible throughout your own class, in order to accomplish this you should use a [member initialization list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) and initialize the `foreign_library` in the constructor member initialization list instead, that way it will be accessible throughout your library, which is what I think you want.

So you would do this:

*own_library.h:*

```
#ifndef own_library_h
#define own_library_h

#include <foreign_library.h>

class own_library {
   public:
       own_library(byte one, byte two, byte three);
   private:
       foreign_library test; // Member variable, so accessible throughout class.
};

#endif
```

and in *own_library.cpp:*

```
#include "own_library.h"

// Initialization list added to constructor.
own_library::own_library(byte one, byte two, byte three) : test {one, two, three} {
   // This is now empty here.
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Are you sure that brackets in ´test{one, two, three}´ are {}? I got error, so I changed {} to () and I got: ´error: no matching function for call to 'foreign_library::foreign_library()'´

Comment: @J.Doe What C++ standard are you using?

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't write it before. I do this things on Arduino.